# I trust you will show forbearance [to/for] me a few minutes more so that I can finish this work

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I trust you will show forbearance [to/for] me a few minutes more so that I can finish this work.

Which is the correct preposition which is to be used with *forbearance* in the above sentence ? I looked for it in a few dictionaries but couldn't find answer for my query.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, ***none!*** At least, I have seldom come across such prepositions following the word *forbearance!*

The standard way of writing the word (in your example) should be...

> "I <del>trust</del> expect that you will show *forbearance* while I finish this work in a few more minutes." or, 
>  "I request you to show *forbearance..."* (more polite)